# How to remap multiple columns in data frame?

Tags: r, mapping, apply

I have a data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(LETTERS[sample(1:5, 15, replace = TRUE)], 5, 3))
df
  V1 V2 V3
1  C  C  A
2  C  D  B
3  E  B  E
4  D  D  C
5  C  D  E
```

I want to remap all of its values according to the map, e.g. like this one:

```
map <- data.frame(id = 1:5, value = LETTERS[1:5])
map
  id value
1  1     A
2  2     B
3  3     C
4  4     D
5  5     E
```

To get the output:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  3  3  1
2  3  4  2
3  5  2  5
4  4  4  3
5  3  4  5
```

I have managed to do that like that:

```
df_id <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, recode, !!! setNames(map$id, map$value)))
```

...but it the slowest method on the planet when data frames are large.
Any better way to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` -

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) map$id[match(x, map$value)])
```

In your approach I think `recode` is making the process slow, extracting value from a named vector should be fast.

```
lookup <- setNames(map$id, map$value)
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) lookup[x])
df
```